# How to see images in tmux

Tags: tmux, w3m

I browse `w3m` with an images plugin. On normal terminals and even (typically minimally-featureful) virtual terminals I can see images. But when I browse with `w3m` in `tmux` the images don't show up.

If this were an `ssh` connection I would probably try `ssh -Y` to let the images through. Is there a way to do something similar with `tmux`?

Comment: How do you see images in "normal" terminals? It pops up a new window, or it will be converted to an ASCII-art form?

Comment: @GaborGarami There is a plugin for `w3m` called `w3m-img` which handles it.

Comment: @GaborGarami The normal <kbd>I</kbd> way of seeing `w3m` images with `feh` is a good comparison though. I would use `ssh -Y` to get the image sent to my computer but I wouldn't be able to see the popup `feh` image from `tmux` because of the same reason as my problem above.

Comment: Check value of `DISPLAY` environment variable before you enter `tmux` session and after you enter to it. ssh -Y works very simple: sends everything to X server defined in `DISPLAY`.

Comment: thanks @GaborGarami. It's `:0`. How would I utilise that?

Comment: Try run xterm from tmux. If it's appears, then DISPLAY value is OK. If not appears, but complains about connection problems to X server, then you have to check value of DISPLAY outside `tmux`, and set to that value inside `tmux`.

Comment: @GaborGarami Thanks! That did pop up a new terminal. But how do I then display the images?

Comment: If it popped up a new terminal, then DISPLAY setting is OK. Try run  `feh` manually on same way as xterm and pass an image as argument. If it pops up with the image, then there is a bug in `w3m` as it does not start feh correctly, report it. If not, then it writes an error message to the terminal, share that with us.

Comment: @GaborGarami Hmm, I tried it again today and my problem has gone away. I'm not sure if it's because I changed something or not. Anyway thank you for spending the time on this discussion. I feel I've learned something new about the back end. Cheers.

Comment: *it's just a guess, but i'll add it for others which will come across this problem/question in future:* showing images even when `w3m-img` is installed, just works for a few terminals like `xterm` and `rxvt`... even with `xterm-256color` it seem to not work. **--** perhaps the text browser with images [`links2`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Links_(web_browser)) would be an alternative for some users.